# Integrate ActiveMQ Classic web console with Tomcat 9.x

Tags: tomcat, activemq-classic, web-console

I tried following ActiveMQ Classic official docs to put `activemq-web-console.war` into Tomcat `webapps` folder and `activemq-all.jar` into Tomcat `lib`, but web console can't be started.

1. I tried Tomcat 5.5/8.0/9.0, with ActiveMQ Classic 5.15/5.18/6.0.1, report listeners failed to start problem
2. I tried Tomcat lower than 5.5 with ActiveMQ 5.10, report exception while processing this request

Preconfigured with ActiveMQ Classic, and Tomcat as following:

1. ActiveMQ Classic with JMX, verifed working with JConsole
   env:

   ```
   ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 "
   ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
   ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access"
   ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
   ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
   ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x"
   ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
   ```
2. `catalina.sh`

   ```
   JAVA_OPTS="-Dwebconsole.type=properties -Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://x.x.x.x:61616 -Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://x.x.x.x:11099/jmxrmi"
   ```

Has anybody tried with a newer version with a successful deployment?

Answer (score 0):

### 1.ActiveMQ 5.18.3 + Tomcat 9.0.84

### 2.JDK-18 required

### 3.Enable activeMQ JMX-192.168.1.1

- useJmx="true" (conf/activemq.xml, broker element)
- JMX parameter change (bin/env)

  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 "
  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access"
  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
  ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.1"

### 4.Tomcat 9.0.84 server on another Computer-192.168.1.2

1. download activemq-web-console.war, and activemq-all.jar from maven central repo
2. place war and jars into right position*

- step1: cp activemq-web-console.war into tomcat9.0.84/webapps/
- step2: cp activemq-all-5.18.3.jar into tomcat9.0.84/lib

3. copy missing jars to tomcat9.0.84/webapps/activemq-web-console/WEB-INF/lib (from apache-activemq-5.18.3.tar.gz, web/lib)

- apache-jsp-8.5.70.jar
- apache-jsp-9.4.53.v20201009.jar
- apache-jstl-9.4.53.v20231009.jar
- taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
- taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar

4. change tomcat9.0.84/bin/catalina.sh

- CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dwebconsole.type=properties -Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://192.168.1.1:61616 -Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.1.1:11099/jmxrmi"

*if you put missing jars above step 3 into tomcat-9.0.84/lib, it will report 404*

### 5.ActiveMQ and Tomcat on same server, works too

just change activemq and tomcat listening ip address

Comment: activeMQ 17.6, activeMQ16.7 works as well with the same configuration as activeMQ18.3

Comment: activeMQ5.15.16, jus place activemq-web-console.-5.15-16war, and activemq-all-5.15.16.jar, there is no missing jar to find